# How to change text color and format code while posting questions

Tags: support, code-formatting, code, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I see again and again that people here ask questions very ably — their code looks like real code, all the tags are in one color and all the commands are in another color. But I don't even know how to change the color of text while typing my question — obviously, there is no such tool here (at least I couldn't find one) - let alone format the code properly. How do I do that here at Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the orange question mark above the top right corner of the reply box. That will explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

For code lines, put four spaces in front of them.

```
void foo(int bar) {
    // vomit
}
```

done. Simples. Oh, orange question mark surely is obvious too?

(The system uses MarkDown formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Write your code, and then highlight it and use the 'code' button above the input box (that's the button consisting of `{ }`).

Answer (score 0):

You put four spaces at the beginning of the line to make it a code block.

You can select a part of your text and press the `{ }` button to add/remove four spaces at the beginning of each line.